# How to enable C++17 in gradle?

Tags: c++, gradle, compiler-errors, c++17

I am using gradle to compile my cpp project.

**build.gradle**

```
compilerArgs.addAll toolChain.map { toolChain ->
    if (toolChain in [ Gcc, Clang ]) {
        return ['-std=++17']
    } else if (toolChain in VisualCpp) {
        return '/std=c++17'
    }
    return []
}
```

If I build my project it comes error

> ```
> > Task :ye:compileDebugCpp FAILED
> ye.cpp
> C:\Qt\6.2.4\mingw_64\include\QtCore/qglobal.h(94): fatal error C1189: #error:  "Qt requires a C++17 compiler, and a suitable 
> value for __cplusplus. On MSVC, you must pass the /Zc:__cplusplus option to the compiler."
> ```

How to solve this error ?

Comment: Without knowing much Gradle, are you sure about `toolChain in VisualCpp`? Should't that be either a direct comparison for equality, or `toolChain in [ VisualCpp ]`?

Comment: I compiled my cpp project after I read this doc and I applied in my build.gradle file  
 https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_cpp_projects.html

Comment: Then the problem might be `return '/std=c++17'` instead. Have you tried `return ['/std=c++17']` (as shown in the documentation, and which you do for GCC and Clang)?

Comment: I tried this `return ['/std=c++17']` but not worked.